# How to change file ownership in Yocto

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I need to change file ownership in Yocto. I have a recipe that creates a directory.
To create a new group and user I added in my image.bbappend:

```
inherit extrausers  
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = " groupadd new_group; \
                       useradd  -g new_group -p '' new_user; \
                       usermod -a -G new_group root \
                     "
```

To add a new directory to my image I added to some_recipe.bbappend:

```
FILES_${PN} = "/dir1/dir2"
do_install_append() {
    install -d ${D}/dir1/dir2
}
```

When I try to use `chown -R my_group.my_user /dir1/dir2` in the above do_install_append() task I get an error that such group and user does't exist. So next, I tried to add the above three lines to image.bbappend file. I get no errors from bitbake but in the final image directory is still own by root.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this in your .bbappend file:

```
pkg_postinst_ontarget:${PN}() {
    chown -R user:group /dir1/dir2
}
```

I think that the problem is that you are trying to change the ownership of the file before Yocto has created the user.